# Leer un archivo de texto y separar el contenido por ":"

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo un programa en Visual Basic, he de mencionar que nunca habia menjado Visual Basic ni C#, pero sé un poco de C++ y Java.

Lo que quiero hacer es leer un .txt que tiene una serie de datos separados por ":", cuando lea el primer dato, realizar una función, después leer el siguiente dato y realizar otra función, ya habiendo leido la primera linea, antes de pasar a la siguiente, realizar otra función.

El contenido del txt está organizado así:

Pedro:Gomez

Camila:Suarez

Juan:Molina

Traté de crear dos label's para obtener cada dato que quiero usar, el primer label contendría el valor del primer dato (Pedro) y el segundo label contendría el segundo Label (Gomez), al tener esos datos guardados en un label, sólo llamaría al texto que tienen para darles uso, pero el código directamente lee todos los datos y a los dos label's les da el último valor (Molina).

De antemano gracias por la(s) respuesta(s).

El código que utilizo para leer el txt y leer los datos separados por ":" es el siguiente (No los desarrollé yo):

```
Private Sub ingresar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ingresar.Click
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog


    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files|*.txt"
    'Abrir documento.

    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then

        Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Me.RichTextBox1.LoadFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)




    End If


    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(":")

        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData

            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    cuenta.Text = currentField
                    password.Text = currentField


                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                        FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Tiene sentido, ya que estás asignando en un bucle el mismo valor que reciba del fichero, del primero al último. El último valor que recogerá la variable `currentField` será ´Molina` y, por tanto, la que recibirán ambos `Labels`.

Comment: ¿Entonces qué podría editar de esa parte del código?, perdón por no tener ni idea, pero la verdad nunca había manejado VB o C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actualización**

He modificado el código y comentado cada línea para que comprendas qué hace cada parte. Básicamente, lo que he hecho es recorrer cada línea del fichero, asignando los valores que están delante y detrás del delimitador a cada `Label`, dando la posibilidad de actuar sobre ellos.

```
Private Sub ingresar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ingresar.Click
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog

    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files|*.txt"
    'Abrir documento.

    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Me.RichTextBox1.LoadFile(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
    End If

    Dim i As Integer = 0 'Contador bucle general
    Dim j As Integer = 1 'Contador bucle interno
    Dim linea As String 'Contador de líneas

    For Each linea In File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName) 'Recoge las líneas del fichero
        Dim partes As String() = linea.Split(New Char() {":"c}) 'Divide las líneas en Strings, en base al delimitador ":"

        For Each parte As String In partes 'Recorre cada palabra de cada línea, y actúa sobre ellas
            If j Mod 2 = 0 Then 'Resto = 0, recoge la primera parte de la línea y la coloca en cuenta.Text
                cuenta.Text = parte
            Else 'Resto != 0, recoge la segunda parte de la línea y la coloca en password.Text
                password.Text = parte
            End If
            j += 1
        Next

        'Actúa sobre "usuario" y "contraseña"
        'Aquí deberías realizar el login

        i += 1 'Contador para cambiar de línea en el fichero
    Next
End Sub
```

El contenido del `Split`, concretamente el delimitador, se explica a fondo en el siguiente enlace:

[Constant and Literal Data Types (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/constant-and-literal-data-types)

**Respuesta original**

Lo que hace tu código es normal. Está recorriendo una serie de `Strings` y la última que encuentra, en este caso, es `Molina`.

Con el planteamiento actual, se me ocurre una forma sencilla de asignar la primera parte del delimitador `:` a `cuenta.Text` y la segunda a `password.Text`. Eso sí, los dos últimos valores siguen siendo los mismos así que al final lo que tú siempre verás será una asignación de la última fila del fichero, es decir, `Juan` en `cuenta.Text` y `Molina` en `password.Text`, aunque realmente los dos `Label` reciban en cada iteración del `For each` cada uno de los valores que contiene el fichero.

```
Try
    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each value As String In currentRow
        If (i Mod 2 = 0) Then
            cuenta.Text = value 'Añade el valor de la izquierda
        Else
            password.Text = value 'Añade el valor de la derecha
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
            FileIO.MalformedLineException
    MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
    "is not valid and will be skipped.")
End Try
```

De esta forma, obtendrías algo como lo siguiente:

[image: Demo del comportamiento del código]

Como ves, asigna el valor `Juan` en `cuenta.Text` y `Molina`en `password.Text`. Eso sí, siempre asignará los valores de la última línea. En base a tu pregunta, es lo que he comprendido que buscas.

Si lo que buscas es realizar alguna acción tras leer cada línea del fichero, coméntalo y vemos cómo plantearlo.

Comment: Primero necesitaría que en cuenta.Text se asigne el valor de Pedro y en password.text el valor de Gomez... Para luego iniciar sesión, luego hacerlo con los siguientes datos (Camila:Suarez) y por último con Juan:Molina, creo que me hago una idea de cómo hacerlo... Aunque agradecería si me guías, igual muy buena respuesta.

Comment: @AndrésGonzález edito la respuesta en base a lo que has comentado

Comment: Entiendo... Entonces para ejecutar la acción que quiero, lo hago dentro del `if` o `else` según necesite, en mi caso me sería muy conveniente usar un timer, ¿ya sólo sería agregarlo y que cada tanto tiempo se ejecute la acción?

Comment: Realmente no sería dentro del `if`o `else`, sería justo después. Lo que hace el `if-Else` dentro del `For Each` es rellenar los `Label` `cuenta.Text` y `password.Text`. Deberías realizar las acciones pertinentes justo después del `For Each`, es decir tras haber obtenido los valores de usuario y contraseña en el `If-Else`. No hace falta que utilices los `Label` realmente, ya que la variable `parte` te proporciona esos valores ya.

Comment: Ya para comprender un poco mejor el código, `Dim partes As String() = linea.Split(New Char() {":"c})` ¿Cuál es la función del `{":"c}` específicamente de la `c`?

Comment: Lo que hace `c` es forzar a que se interprete como `Char` y no como `String` lo que haya entre comillas, en este caso, `":"`. En la documentación de Microsoft está explicado. Voy a ver si lo encuentro y lo pongo como referencia en la respuesta

Comment: @AndrésGonzález marca la respuesta como correcta si te ha sido útil y así guias a usuarios que busquen temas similares.

Answer (score 0):

Usando la función Split puedes separar cada linea con el delimitador ":" y luego ejecutar la función que desees con cada parte de lo que resulta de Split.

Luego por cada nueva linea puedes ejecutar otra función.

En el siguiente ejemplo solo se genera un mensaje por cada parte dividida de la linea en turno, es decir, dos mensajes por linea, luego se genera otro mensaje al ingresar a la siguiente linea ( antes de hacer el nuevo Split para esa segunda linea.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Public Sub test()
        'la linea dividida por el caracter :
        Dim tx() As String

        ' abrir el archivo txt
        Using f As StreamReader = New StreamReader("C:\test.txt")
            ' Almacenar contenidos en esta cadena.
            Dim line As String

            'lee la primera fila
            line = f.ReadLine

            'recorrer cada fila del archivo.
            Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
                'separar la linea con el delimitador :
                tx = line.Split(":")
                'mostrar mensaje de cada parte de la linea
                MsgBox(tx(0))
                MsgBox(tx(1))
                'se lee la siguiente linea
                line = f.ReadLine
                MsgBox("Esta es otra linea")
            Loop
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call test()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ¿En vez de usar valores como cero y uno, podría reemplazarlos por una variable de tipo entero cada vez que lee un dato separado por `:`, es decir `Dim i As Integer                                                                            MsgBox(tx(i))
MsgBox(tx(i))`

Comment: Por cada linea se devuelven solo 2 valores para el array, no hay necesidad de agregar una variable para eso, ademas, el ciclo se esta aplicando solo a las lineas, no al array que resulta al usar Split en cada linea.
Si haces pruebas con ese código, veras que si te devuelve los datos como lo indicas en tu pregunta, ya tu veras que haces con el. por ejemplo, asignarlos en TextBox y luego hacer algo con esos datos.
`txtCuenta.Text = tx(0)
txtPass.Text = tx(1)`
abajo de esto va el código que usara esos datos para hacer lo que desees.